# Split Textview and Spannable String

Tags: java, android, android-studio, split, textview

guys i'm using this code below to get a textview and split the text, the text is "3,48"

```
TxReal = view.findViewById(R.id.valorLMin);
String ValorSeparado [] = TxReal.getText().toString().split(",");
```

after i using this to span

```
SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString(ValorSeparado[0]);
  s1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f),0,1,0);
    TxReal.setText(s1);
```

but when I use SetText and see it in my layout, I can't see the rest of the text just the first character "3", what should I do to show all the text with only the first largest number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need split text, try this

```
String value = TxReal.getText().toString();
SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString(value);
s1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, value.indexOf(','), 0);
TxReal.setText(s1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this form and my problem was solved